# How to unwind column contents into new columns based on condition in another column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called my mydf. I want to split the contents in columns `ASM` and `GPM` based on the format given in the `FORMAT` column and get the `result`. So basically, there will be as many columns for ASM and GPM columns as there are total unique elements (i.e. 5 different unique elements) in FORMAT column separated by `:` to unwind in the `result`. Then need to place the right value in the right columns (with .GT, .FT, and so on) as indicated in `FORMAT` column.

```
 mydf <- structure(list(`#CHROM` = c(1L, 1L, 1L), POS = c(10490L, 10493L, 
10494L), FORMAT = c("GT:FT:GQ", "GT:PS:GL", "GT:PS:FT"), ASM = c("1/1:TRUE:4,2,333", 
"./.:.:.", "0/1:.:VQLOW"), GPM = c("./.:.:.", "1/1:4:2,233", 
"0/1:22:VQHIGH")), .Names = c("#CHROM", "POS", "FORMAT", "ASM", 
"GPM"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

result:

```
 result <- structure(list(`#CHROM` = c(1L, 1L, 1L), POS = c(10490L, 10493L, 
10494L), FORMAT = c("GT:FT:GQ", "GT:PS:GL", "GT:PS:FT"), ASM.GT = c("1/1", 
"./.", "0/1"), ASM.FT = c("TRUE", NA, "VQLOW"), ASM.GQ = c("4,2,333", 
NA, NA), ASM.PS = c(NA, NA, NA), ASM.GL = c(NA, NA, NA), GPM.GT = c("./.", 
"1/1", "0/1"), GPM.FT = c(NA, NA, "VQHIGH"), GPM.GQ = c(NA, NA, 
NA), GPM.PS = c(NA, 4L, 22L), GPM.GL = c(NA, 2233L, NA)), .Names = c("#CHROM", 
"POS", "FORMAT", "ASM.GT", "ASM.FT", "ASM.GQ", "ASM.PS", "ASM.GL", 
"GPM.GT", "GPM.FT", "GPM.GQ", "GPM.PS", "GPM.GL"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: You could try `library(splitstackshape);library(data.table);dM <- melt(setDT(mydf), id.var=1:3) %>% cSplit(c("FORMAT", "value"), ":", "long");dM1 <- dM[, variable:= paste(variable, FORMAT, sep=".")];dcast(dM1[, -3, with=FALSE], ...~variable, value.var="value")[, FORMAT:= mydf$FORMAT][]`

Comment: @akrun Thank you so much . Your solutions are always very helpful. I am not sure what this bit is doing: `dcast(dM1[, -3, with=FALSE], ...~variable, value.var="value")[, FORMAT:= mydf$FORMAT][]` . This generates error: `Error in parse(text = x)[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: Based on the example you provided, it's working for me.  I am using `splitstackshape_1.4.2` and `data.table_1.9.6`  I think you got a more compact solution below .

Comment: @akrun It works when I use R in linux Terminal, but gives me error while running in R studio. Isn't it weird?

Comment: I tested it on R console and not on Rstudio.  It may have some clashes with some other functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it appears that the number of values in each of the columns to be split is the same, we can take advantage of the ability of `dcast` in "data.table" to handle multiple `value.var`s.

The splitting can be done by `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package.

```
library(splitstackshape)
dcast(cSplit(mydf, c("FORMAT", "ASM", "GPM"), ":", "long"), 
      `#CHROM` + POS ~ FORMAT, value.var = c("ASM", "GPM"))
#    #CHROM   POS ASM_FT ASM_GL  ASM_GQ ASM_GT ASM_PS GPM_FT GPM_GL GPM_GQ GPM_GT GPM_PS
# 1:      1 10490   TRUE     NA 4,2,333    1/1     NA      .     NA      .    ./.     NA
# 2:      1 10493     NA      .      NA    ./.      .     NA  2,233     NA    1/1      4
# 3:      1 10494  VQLOW     NA      NA    0/1      . VQHIGH     NA     NA    0/1     22
```

Note that `"#CHROM"` is a very R-unfriendly column name since the `#` is the comment character.

If you need to add back in the "FORMAT" column, add a `[, FORMAT:= mydf$FORMAT][]` to the end of the `dcast` above.

I'm presuming that you can handle further cleaning from here (for example, replacing `.` with `NA` and removing the thousand comma separator wherever it appears.

Comment: Thanks, but this generates error `Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: It works when I use R in linux Terminal, but gives me error while running in R studio.

Comment: @MAPK, your RStudio installation might be using a different library location, and thus may have different versions of the packages than what you get in the terminal. Make sure that `packageVersion("data.table")` is 1.9.6 or greater both in the terminal and in RStudio. That's the only thing I can think of off the top of my head. My answer was posted from RStudio on an Ubuntu system.